# Problema con glob.glob en Python

Tags: python, array

Tengo problemas con la sentencia `glob.glob`.

No me permite agregar imágenes de dos carpetas a array

```
import glob

paths=['Quemaduras/tipo a/entrenamiento',
       'Quemaduras/tipo b/entrenamiento'
       ]
labels=[]
features=[]

for label, path in enumerate(paths):
    for filename in glob.glob(path+"*.jpg"):
        print(label)
        print(path)
        print(filename)
        # img=cv2.imread(filename)
        # features.append(getFeatures(img))
        # labels.append(label)

features=np.array(features)
labels=np.array(labels)
```

Comment: Te falta un "/" al final de "path": `for filename in glob.glob(path+"/*.jpg"):`

Answer (score 2):

Si en lugar de `glob` usas la moderna librería `pathlib` puedes hacer lo mismo en la forma siguiente, menos proclive a errores puesto que no te puedes olvidar el utilizar el separador `"/"` como te ha pasado, además de que el código sería más portable puesto que `pathlib` usa los separadores correctos para cada operativo.

```
from pathlib import Path

paths=['Quemaduras/tipo a/entrenamiento',
       'Quemaduras/tipo b/entrenamiento'
       ]


for label, path in enumerate(paths):
    for filename in Path(path).glob("*.jpg"):
        print(label)
        print(path)
        print(filename)
```

**NOTA IMPORTANTE**. En el bucle `for filename` la variable `filename` ya no es un mero string, sino un objeto de tipo `pathlib.Path` y por tanto tiene muchos métodos de utilidad muy adecuados para trabajar con ficheros. Por ejemplo, si quisieras obtener sólo la extensión del fichero usarías `filename.suffix` (y obtendrías en este caso la cadena `".jpg"`) y si lo que quieres es el nombre sin la ruta ni la extensión pondrías `filename.stem`, y si quieres el nombre de la carpeta que lo contiene `filename.parent`, etc.

A pesar de que no es una cadena, se puede imprimir con `print()`, lo que lo convierte en cadena y verás un resultado "normal". Además la mayoría de las funciones que esperan un nombre de fichero como parámetro, admiten que le pases este objeto como parámetro. En caso de que no funcione porque la función sólo admita cadenas, puedes pasarle `str(filename)`, o mejor aún `filename.absolute()` que devuelve una cadena con la ruta absoluta del fichero, que puedes usar para abrirlo y leerlo sin que dependa desde qué carpeta lo estás haciendo.